# Structure Reference and Dereference Operators

Tags: c++

Suppose I define this structure:

```
struct Point {
   double x, y;
};
```

Now, suppose I create a dynamic array of this type:

```
Point *P = new Point[10];
```

Why do I use `P[k].x` and `P[k].y` instead of `P[k]->x` and `P[k]->y` to access the `k`-th point's elements?

I thought you had to use the latter for pointers.

Comment: You don't use `P.x` and `P.y`. Try it.

Comment: `P.x` and `P.y` would be errors. I guess you mean `P[0].x` and `P[1].y`, and that makes all the difference. Short answer `P` might be a pointer, but `P[0]` isn't, it's an object..

Comment: Now for fun, try this `Point **P = new Point*[10]; p[k]->x = 1.0;`. That compiles because now you have an array of pointers, not an array of objects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, you use `p[index].x` and `p[index].y` to access elements of the `struct` inside an array, because in this case you are using a pointer to refer to a dynamically allocated array.

The `ptr->member` operator is simply a shorthand for `(*ptr).member`. In order to use it, you need a pointer on the left-hand side:

```
Point *p = new Point;
p->x = 12.34;
p->y = 56.78;
```

Note that even for a dynamically allocated array the `->` operator would have worked:

```
Point *p = new Point[10];
p->x = 12.34;
p->y = 56.78;
```

This is equivalent to

```
p[0].x = 12.34;
p[0].y = 56.78;
```

because a pointer to an array is equal to the pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have created a dynamically allocated *array* that holds `Point` objects, not `Point*`. You access each member via `operator[]`:

```
p[0].x = 42;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I use P[k].x and P[k].y instead of P[k]->x and P[k]->y to access the k-th point's elements?

Because `P[k]` is *not* a pointer, it is the object at the `k`th position and its type is `Point`, not `Point*`. For example:

```
Point p = P[0]; // Copy 0th object
p.x; // Access member x
Point* pp = &(P[0]); // Get address of 0th element, equivalent to just P
pp->x; // Access member x
```

Answer (score 1):

In general the arrow `->` operator is used to dereference a pointer. But in this case, P is an array of Points. if P was an array of Point pointers then you would have uses the latter

Answer (score -1):

I believe the Q relates to **C Indirection**

In C, an array name **IS** a variable of type ( pointer to the first memory location allocated to / for the array )

Specifying an index ( square-bracket notation of, `[n]` ) results in **indirection**.

Hence,

```
PointerA    behaves like   ArrayA
*PointerA   behaves like   ArrayA[]
```

For variables of type pointer, the asterisk (*) is the *Indirection Operator* used to,

Access the value ( stored **WITHIN** a memory location )

---

Given the code example in the original Q, assuming P is assigned to memory-address location `ADDR-01`

`P` refers to `ADDR-01` not what's stored **WITHIN** `ADDR-01`

`P[0]` refers to what's stored **WITHIN** `ADDR-01` thru `ADDR-16` with the 1st `8 bytes` of `P[0]` being `x` and the 2nd `8 bytes` of `P[0]` being `y`

`P[0]` occupies ADDR-01 thru ADDR-16 ( 16 bytes ) because a `double` is 8 bytes and x and y are both defined as `double`